# One-hot encode along arbitrary dimension with NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, one-hot-encoding

Given a numpy array with arbitrarily many dimensions, I would like to be able to one-hot encode any of these dimensions. For example, say I have an array `a` of shape `(10, 20, 30, 40)` I might want to one hot encode the second dimension, i.e. transform `a` such that the result only contains values `0` and `1` and `a[i, :, j, k]` contains exactly one zero entry for every choice of `i`, `j` and `k` (at the position of the previous maximum value along that dimension).

I thought about first obtaining `a.argmax(axis=1)` and then using `np.ogrid` to turn that into indices pointing to the maxima but I can't figure out the details. I'm also worried about memory consumption with this approach.

Is there an easy way to do this (ideally requiring little additional memory)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way with `array-assignment` -

```
def onehotencode_along_axis(a, axis):
    # Setup o/p hot encoded bool array 
    h = np.zeros(a.shape,dtype=bool)
    idx = a.argmax(axis=axis)

    # Setup same dimensional indexing array as the input
    idx = np.expand_dims(idx, axis) # Thanks to @Peter

    # Finally assign True values
    np.put_along_axis(h,idx,1,axis=axis)
    return h
```

Sample runs on `2D` case -

```
In [109]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: a = np.random.randint(11,99,(4,5))

In [110]: a
Out[110]: 
array([[55, 58, 75, 78, 78],
       [20, 94, 32, 47, 98],
       [81, 23, 69, 76, 50],
       [98, 57, 92, 48, 36]])

In [112]: onehotencode_along_axis(a, axis=0)
Out[112]: 
array([[False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True, False, False]])

In [113]: onehotencode_along_axis(a, axis=1)
Out[113]: 
array([[False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False]])
```

Sample run for verification on higher (multidimensional) `5D` case -

```
In [114]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: a = np.random.randint(11,99,(2,3,4,5,6))
     ...: for i in range(a.ndim):
     ...:     out = onehotencode_along_axis(a, axis=i)
     ...:     print np.allclose(out.sum(axis=i),1)
True
True
True
True
True
```

If you need the final output as an `int` array with `0`s and `1`s, use a view on the boolean output array :

`onehotencode_along_axis(a, axis=0).view('i1')` and so on.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. I have never seen `put_along_axis` used before, very neat.

Comment: One suggestion: couldn't you replace the whole `idx_shp` business by `idx = np.expand_dims(idx, axis)`?

Comment: @Peter Great suggestion, thanks! Certainly and looks much better/idiomatic now.